# H2 Database OutOfMemoryError on android?

Tags: java, android, h2

I'm trying using H2 on android for my app one of the main table is:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
>                   + "tbl_content("
>                   + "date DATE PRIMARY KEY, "
>                   + "content OTHER);

When I'm adding data to it, After insert some data to this table I get the below error:
I change my code many times(Change read file, I also split my file and so...) but nothing change and every time I get this error again and again: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Capacity:`

I also add `android:largeHeap="true"` to manifest file but nothing change!!!

```
03-28 15:46:44.786   9512-11006/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 81K, 27% free 12064K/16316K, paused 84ms, total 85ms
03-28 15:46:44.786   9512-11006/? E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 2097168-byte allocation.
03-28 15:46:44.796   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ "MVStore background writer nio:/data/data/com.example.me/files/dbx.mv.db" daemon prio=5 tid=14 RUNNABLE
03-28 15:46:44.796   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb4fbe238 self=0xb8714e70
03-28 15:46:44.796   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=11006 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1200532792
03-28 15:46:44.796   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=R schedstat=( 4230000000 770000000 168 ) utm=412 stm=11 core=0
03-28 15:46:44.796   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:~56)
03-28 15:46:44.796   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer.grow(WriteBuffer.java:308)
03-28 15:46:44.816   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer.ensureCapacity(WriteBuffer.java:295)
03-28 15:46:44.816   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer.put(WriteBuffer.java:157)
03-28 15:46:44.816   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.writeValue(ValueDataType.java:289)
03-28 15:46:44.826   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.writeValue(ValueDataType.java:381)
03-28 15:46:44.826   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.write(ValueDataType.java:189)
03-28 15:46:44.826   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$VersionedValueType.write(TransactionStore.java:1695)
03-28 15:46:44.826   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.Page.write(Page.java:737)
03-28 15:46:44.826   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.Page.writeUnsavedRecursive(Page.java:818)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.Page.writeUnsavedRecursive(Page.java:824)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNowTry(MVStore.java:1060)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:976)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.commitAndSave(MVStore.java:965)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2373)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:2586)
03-28 15:46:44.836   9512-11006/? I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 03-28 15:46:44.836  9512:11006 W/dalvikvm ]
    threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aaaba8)
03-28 15:46:44.866   9512-11006/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: MVStore background writer nio:/data/data/com.example.me/files/dbx.mv.db
    Process: com.example.me, PID: 9512
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Capacity: 2097152
            at org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer.grow(WriteBuffer.java:310)
            at org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer.ensureCapacity(WriteBuffer.java:295)
            at org.h2.mvstore.WriteBuffer.put(WriteBuffer.java:157)
            at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.writeValue(ValueDataType.java:289)
            at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.writeValue(ValueDataType.java:381)
            at org.h2.mvstore.db.ValueDataType.write(ValueDataType.java:189)
            at org.h2.mvstore.db.TransactionStore$VersionedValueType.write(TransactionStore.java:1695)
            at org.h2.mvstore.Page.write(Page.java:737)
            at org.h2.mvstore.Page.writeUnsavedRecursive(Page.java:818)
            at org.h2.mvstore.Page.writeUnsavedRecursive(Page.java:824)
            at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNowTry(MVStore.java:1060)
            at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.storeNow(MVStore.java:976)
            at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.commitAndSave(MVStore.java:965)
            at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.writeInBackground(MVStore.java:2373)
            at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$BackgroundWriterThread.run(MVStore.java:2586)
03-28 15:46:44.916      413-680/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.me/.view.SettingsActivity
03-28 15:46:45.856    9512-9512/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-28 15:46:46.316    9512-9512/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-28 15:46:48.576    9512-9512/? E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.me.view.SettingsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b51f0f90 V.E..... R....... 0,0-320,140} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
            at com.example.me.util.Updater.onPreExecute(Updater.java:60)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.example.me.util.Downloader.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:161)
            at com.example.me.util.Downloader.onPostExecute(Downloader.java:18)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the H2 problem this errors come from the other part of app because the heap size is small and I try to read big chunk of a file and insert it to database, I change the program logic on reading file and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, this is not related to this topic but I was wondering is there any tutorial about how to install H2 on Android?

Comment: Hi you don't need to install the H2 on android just use the H2 jar file in your project, also you can use small version of H2 this is your choice, **But the important note is the proguard have some error on this then you have to ignore this jar on config file**